# Alternatives to 333MHz DDR SDRAM (PC2700) RAM

Tags: upgrade, memory

I'm reinstalling a friends (very) old laptop with Windows XP. I recommend he upgrade the 512MB RAM in order to keep both sanity and general well-being.

It's an Dell Inspiron 8600, and the [manual](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/ins8500/en/8500/OM/8600/i8600-om.pdf) (sorry, that's a 3,5MB pdf, but check out page 128 for the specs) says it supports a maximum of 2GB 333MHz DDR SDRAM (PC2700) RAM. However it turns out those modules are impossible to find today.

What other newer types of RAM can I safely use in this machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably use PC3200 DDR SDRAM. The motherboard should lower the rate of the RAM to 2700.

Comment: Thanks. What about the clock-speed?  I checked, but I can't find any PC3200 DDR-SDRAM, only PC2-3200, and even that doesn't seem to be readily available.

Comment: The rate is lowered by reducing the clock speed.